# Зачем присваивать background к body?

Tags: css

Я тут посмотрел что тот же yandex, google, webmoney и т.д. присваивают `background` с белым цветом к `body`. Зачем это, разве по умолчанию цвет фона страницы не белый?

И еще: ни кто не подскажет начинающему верстальщику статью (или сами объясните) про основные рецепты перед началом верстки? Типа применения `display: block` к html5 тегам и т.д.

Comment: _Зачем это, разве по умолчанию цвет фона страницы не белый?_ Зависит от браузера

Comment: @Grundy понял, спасибо. Не подскажете у какого браузера цвет не белый?

Comment: раньше у Netscape :-) был светло-серый фон, из современных не могу сказать. Ну и немного спецификации: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background

Comment: Если у вас два вопроса, лучше их задавать отдельно

Comment: @Polyakov, как минимум у Firefox можно задать в `Настройках — Содержимое` цвета и шрифты по умолчанию. В каких-то браузерах наверняка это зависит от темы графической оболочки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background` у `body` не во всех браузерах раньше белый был.

Как я помню, начинал верстать и была такая проблема что, в каком то браузере был не белый, а серый и решения данной проблемы применить к `body` - `background`.
Тем более есть возможность в некоторых браузерах изменить стандартный цвет. И когда вы рассчитываете белую вёрстку, вся идея рушиться!

Есть [старая книжка](http://www.postroika.ru/html/), но я до сих пор под впечатлением (но для html4)

А так же есть хорошая русифицированная библиотека знаний по 
[HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но думаете стоит учиться по книге которая была обновлена последний раз в 2004 году? Базовое представление я имею, а вот что-то актуальное на текущий момент я думаю там не найду.